# Should this be considered an SQL injection risk?

Tags: activerecord, sql-injection

Say I have a Rails app with 3 models: `Job`, `Contractor`, `Bid`. When a contractor bids on a job, a bid is created with the appropriate `contractor_id` and `job_id`. Now I'd like to define a Job scope that, given a contractor, returns the jobs they have *not* yet bid on:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :not_bid_on_by, -> (contractor) do
    joins(%{
      LEFT JOIN bids ON bids.job_id = jobs.id
      AND bids.contractor_id = #{ contractor.id }
    }).where(bids: { id: nil })
  end
end
```

Despite the fact that a value is interpolated directly into the `joins` string, I can't think of a case where this example would be vulnerable to SQL injection, since it's only interpolating an `id` field from the given argument. I know it's bad practice in general, but this seems like a benign instance.

If I'm wrong and this *is* a security risk, is there a safer way to do it? ActiveRecord doesn't seem to have a way of safely interpolating into the `joins` string like it does for `where` (with `?` or named parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ActiveRecord's `sanitize_sql_array` method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_array

Example:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :not_bid_on_by, -> (contractor) do
    joins( sanitize_sql_array [%{
      LEFT JOIN bids ON bids.job_id = jobs.id
      AND bids.contractor_id = ?
    }, contractor.id]).where(bids: { id: nil })
  end
end
```